# How to compile and run assembly code using masm in OS X?

Tags: xcode, macos, assembly

My question is simple:

Is there any way I can test/run/debug my 32-bit assembly code on a Mac?

I'm taking an Intro to Assembly Language class, but I don't always have access to a pc.
I have xCode and I know it should be able to run NSAM, but that doesn't really help.
I have to use MASM because that is what we use in class and if it doesn't compile then I get a 0.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3):

masm is microsoft specific.  You can use `nasm`

As far as access to PC is concerned, why not run windows in a virtual machine (e.g. virtualbox or vmware fusion or parallels workstation)  I run windows XP in a VM on all of my machines -- some tools, like HP iLO, require .NET framework or IE or some other strange windows-specific package ...

Answer (score 0):

I just successfully did this using the DOSBOX emulator.

Just download DOSBOX, type `mount c ~/path/to/8086folder` to create a C drive, then `C:` to switch to the emulated C drive.